# Can I download source code which has deployed with github from Heroku?

Tags: django, git, heroku

I have deployed my django-app on heroku with Github.
It is test server so I am using sqlitedb.
But because of the dyno manager, my sqlitedb resets everyday.
So I am going to download only db on heroku.

I tried this command.

`heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME`

But this clones empty repository.

And when I run `$heroku run bash -a APP-NAME` command, I got ETIMEOUT error.

Is there any other way to download the source code on heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do with `git` is not possible because changes to the database is not versioned.

The command to run bash on Heroku is `heroku run bash`, not `heroku bash run`. You may have to specify the app using the `-a` flag: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run

Comment: yes i have run ``heoku run bash -a myappname``

Comment: But I have got ETIMEOUT error.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved with downloading the application slug.

If you have not used git to deploy your application, or using `heroku git:clone` has only created an empty repository, you can download the slug that was build when you application was last deployed.

First, install the heroku-slugs CLI plugin with `heroku plugins:install heroku-slugs`,

then run:

`heroku slugs:download -a APP_NAME`

This will download and compress your slug into a directory with the same name as your application.